# Punctuation in "may I suggest"

Tags: punctuation

Do we need to put question mark at the end of a sentence that starts with "may I suggest"? I have seen both used but I am unsure which one is correct.

For example: "May I suggest you read the rules"

Which punctuation mark should I use, a full stop or a question mark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bare statement "I suggest you read the rules." requires a period.
Starting the sentence with *may*, as in "May I suggest you read the rules?"
seems to turn it into a question.

This site shows examples of *may* in this sense used in expressions with and without question marks:
[thefreedictionary modal auxiliary verbs - may](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Modal-Auxiliary-Verbs-May.htm)

> **Making a polite offer**
> Like *can*, we can use *may* to offer do something for someone else, though it is generally a more polite,
> formal way of doing so. For example:
>
> ```
> “May I help you set the table?”
> “May we be of assistance in any way?”
> ```
>
> **As a rhetorical device**
> Sometimes, we use *may* in this way as a rhetorical device to politely introduce or emphasize an opinion or
> sentiment about something, in which case we invert may with the
> subject. For instance:
>
> ```
> “May I just say, this has been the most wonderful experience of my life.”
> “May we be clear that our firm will not be involved in such a dubious plan.”
> “May I be frank: this is not what I was hoping for.”
> ```

To me, your original example with a question mark suggests a rising intonation, and sounds polite, while the one ending with a period suggests a flat intonation and is less polite.